# Периодически отваливается Push & Pull в CRM Битрикс 24

Tags: битрикс24

Ставлю минимальную версию Centos 7. Ставлю виртуальную машину Битрикс. Ставлю пробную версию "коробки" или разворачиваю Бэкап. Всё устанавливается/разворачивается корректно. Проверяю работу системы (Панель управления->Настройки->Инструменты->Проверка системы) и из 10-20 проверок вылетает ошибка работы "Бизнес-функции портала". То есть он то работает то не работает.

Проверка:

[image: Зависает на 30%]

Результат проверки:

[image: Результат проверки]

*(Все конфиги формируются автоматически)*

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: 1. Корректно ли установлен SSL-сертификат?
2. Открыты ли необходимые порты?
3. Есть ли ошибка работы с сокетами?
4. Совпадение ключа в настройках модуля Push&Pull и в настройках push-server.

Comment: @NikolajSarry на всё ответ  - да.

Comment: Попробуйте переподключить модуль. И протестируйте работу. Может есть ошибка при тесте, а по факту работает.

Comment: @NikolajSarry, работает. Но почему при тесте ошибки?

Comment: Попустить должно со временем. Ответа на этот вопрос нет даже у разработчиков битрикса.